# Outer join query FROM_TABLE Flag required

Tags: oracle

I want one flag in output of full outer join in oracle saying from_table which show this tows is fron which table in outer join.

For ex 
A full outer join will give you the union of A and B, i.e. all the rows in A and all the rows in B. If something in A doesn't have a corresponding datum in B, then the B portion is null, and vice versa.

```
select * from a FULL OUTER JOIN b on a.a = b.b;

 a   |  b
-----+-----
   1 | null
   2 | null
   3 |    3
   4 |    4
null |    6
null |    5
```

I need below output:

```
a   |  b | from_table
-----+-----
   1 | null | A
   2 | null | A
   3 |    3 | both
   4 |    4 | both
null |    6 | B
null |    5 | B
```

Kindly suggest the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select a.*, b.*,
       case when a.a is not null and b.b is not null then 'both'
            when a.a is not null then 'a'
            else 'b'
       end as from_table
from a 
FULL OUTER JOIN b on a.a = b.b;
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3025b/11)

Comment: Thank you so much @juergen d

Comment: a little rectification needed ( gives ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected ).

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan: Are you sure you applied it correctly?

Comment: yes, i  commented for your previous edit(about 8 hours ago), but it's true now.

Answer (score 0):

It's eligible to use `nvl` and `nvl2` functions consecutively :

```
select a, b, decode(sign(nvl2(x,1,0)*nvl2(y,1,0)),1,'both',nvl(x,y)) "from_table"
  from
(
 select a.*, b.*, nvl2(a,'A',null) x, nvl2(b,'B',null) y 
   from a FULL OUTER JOIN b on a.a = b.b order by a,b
 );
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3025b/1)